# Needed help with solving Ordinary or Singular Points, Power Series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, singular-integrals

$$y''+xy = 3-e^2x$$

Hey guys, it came up in a homework. Need a solution around 0(zero) power series. I doubt it can be solved by differential equations or power series.
It would be great if anyone helps me.

Appreciated for solutions.

Comment: What have you tried?  Let $y$ be a power series in $x$, plug it in, and equate the terms of the same order in $x$.  Keep going until you get tired.

Comment: Thank you, I will try.